# ntlk python frenchStemmer

Tags: python, nltk

I an trying to initialize `FrenchStemmer`:

```
stemmer = nltk.stem.FrenchStemmer('french')
```

and the error is:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'FrenchStemmer'

Has anyone seen this error before?

Comment: You need to upvote and select the tick mark to the right answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because nltk.stem has **no** module called as **FrenchStemmer**.

The **French stemmer** available is in **SnowballStemmer()** and you can access it by

```
import nltk
stemmer=nltk.stem.SnowballStemmer('french')
```

or by

```
import nltk
stemmer=nltk.stem.snowball.FrenchStemmer()
```

Comment: Your suppose to upvote the correct answer and then mark it correct by clicking the tick sign